# Can you set a variable for "this" in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm doing a tutorial where they use:

```
c = this;
```

When I try it "c" is highlighted in red.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: You can set a variable to `this`, assuming it's the same type of the class and you're not in a static context. You're probably violating one of those conditions.

Comment: or `c` isn't declared

Comment: the error is "Cannot resolve symbol c"

Comment: You haven't declared the variable `c` then, as @SergeyGlotov said.

Comment: how do you declare it? what type of variable is "this"?

Comment: `this` refers to the instance of your class that you're inside. So if you want to store in a variable, the variable has to be the same type of the class itself (or a parent).

Comment: Paste your code here - I am sure we can suggest something to solve the problem. The solution really depends on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Simple, you need declare it first before use:

```
YourActivity c = this; // or SomeOtherClass c =this;
```

Comment: Additionally could be a field (or declared earlier). It's basics.

Comment: just an example, don't be tooooooooooo picky

Comment: Well right that's my point, there's a lot of ways of expressing the same thing; It helps to know those different ones.